# EXEC STORE PROCEDURE IN NODEJS (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, stored-procedure, sequelize.js, sequelize

Estoy ejecutando un Store Procedure en node. El mismo lo traigo como JSON desde el servidor SQL.

El problema es que cuando lo llamas, me trae más datos y me los corta.

Los datos adicionales que aporta es el nombre de la columna.

CODIGO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: SQL EXEC]

como se puede ver enJSO_F5 ....

CONSOLE:

[image: Console.Log]

en la imagen de la consola, marque con un 1 el punto donde se cortan los datos y agregueael nombre de la columna

EJEMPLO: "Ciudad A" + NOMBRE DE COLUMA + "Autonomía de Buenos Aires".

Esto esta mal.

Deberías traerme los datos uno tras otro.

"Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires"

si copio el resultado que me devuelve el SQL esto funciona (lo fuerzo en una variable) es decir que cuando lo llamo con la función es donde se produce el error

STORE PROCEDURE:
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[OrdenesDeVentaAProcesar]    Script Date: 18/1/2021 14:56:15 ******/

Store Procedure

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[OrdenesDeVentaAProcesar]
AS

-- ORDEN DE VENTA
select comprobante.fec

ha as fecha,
comprobante.idcomprobante as pedido_id,
'+' as tipo_operacion,
'' as tipo_pedido,
'Suscripción #' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(6), comprobante.idsuscripcion)) as referencia,
'' as observaciones,

--COBRO
suscripcion.idmediocobro as [tipo_pago.id], 
mediocobro.Descripcion as [tipo_pago.nombre],
10 as [tipo_pago.dias_vencimiento],
'1234452525215' as [tipo_pago.tarjetaDA], --nro de tarjeta, solo DA
dateadd(dd, 10, fecha) as fecha_vencimiento,

canalventa.idCanalVenta as [vendedor.id], -- canal de venta
canalventa.descripcion as [vendedor.nombre], -- canal de venta

--CLIENTE
cliente.idCliente as [cliente.id], 
Cliente.razonsocial as [cliente.nombre_fiscal],
Cliente.razonsocial as [cliente.nombre_comercial],
ClienteDatosContacto.numero as [cliente.telefono],
LOWER(ClienteDatosContacto.email) as [cliente.email],
'' as [cliente.condicion_impositiva],
Cliente.cuit as [cliente.id_fiscal],

--TIPO CLIENTE
1 as [tipo_cliente.id],
'suscripcion' as [tipo_cliente.nombre],

--DOMICILIO FISCAL
clientedomicilio.idclientedomicilio as [domicilio_fiscal.id],
UPPER(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.calle)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.numero)) + 
CASE WHEN RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.piso) <> '' and RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.piso) <> '-' THEN ' - PISO: ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.piso)) ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.departamento) <> ''  and RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.departamento) <> '-'  THEN ' DPTO: ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ClienteDomicilio.departamento)) ELSE '' END 
,char(9),''))as [domicilio_fiscal.calle],
ClienteDomicilio.cpa as [domicilio_fiscal.codpostal],
RIGHT('00000' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(5), ClienteDomicilio.idLocalidad))), 5) as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.id],
LTRIM(RTRIM(cdlocalidad.nombre)) as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.nombre],
RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(2), ClienteDomicilio.idProvincia))), 2) as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.provincia.id],
LTRIM(RTRIM(cdprovincia.nombre)) as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.provincia.nombre],
'01' as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.provincia.pais.id],
'ARGENTINA' as [domicilio_fiscal.ciudad.provincia.pais.nombre],

--DOMICILIO ENTREGA
(SELECT 
LectorDireccionEntrega.idLectorDireccionEntrega as id,
UPPER(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.calle)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.numero)) + 
CASE WHEN RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.piso) <> '' and RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.piso) <> '-' THEN ' - PISO: ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.piso)) ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.departamento) <> ''  and RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.departamento) <> '-'  THEN ' DPTO: ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(LectorDireccionEntrega.departamento)) ELSE '' END 
,char(9),''))as calle,
LectorDireccionEntrega.cpa as codpostal,
RIGHT('00000' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(5), LectorDireccionEntrega.idLocalidad))), 5) as [ciudad.id],
LTRIM(RTRIM(ldelocalidad.nombre)) as [ciudad.nombre],
RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(2), LectorDireccionEntrega.idProvincia))), 2) as [ciudad.provincia.id],
LTRIM(RTRIM(ldeprovincia.nombre)) as [ciudad.provincia.nombre],
'01' as [ciudad.provincia.pais.id],
'ARGENTINA' as [ciudad.provincia.pais.nombre],
CASE WHEN entreCalleA is null THEN '' WHEN RTRIM(entreCalleA) <> ''  and RTRIM(entreCalleA) <> '-'  THEN 
UPPER(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(entreCalleA, ''))),char(9),''))  END as [CalleA],
CASE WHEN entreCalleB is null THEN '' WHEN RTRIM(entreCalleB) <> ''  and RTRIM(entreCalleB) <> '-' THEN 
UPPER(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(entreCalleB, ''))),char(9),'')) END as [CalleB]
FROM
LectorDireccionEntrega 
left join provincia ldeprovincia on ldeprovincia.idprovincia = LectorDireccionEntrega.idprovincia
left join localidad ldelocalidad on ldelocalidad.idlocalidad = LectorDireccionEntrega.idlocalidad
WHERE LectorDireccionEntrega.idLectorDireccionEntrega =  (select 18) --(SELECT distinct comprobantedetalle.idLectorDireccionEntrega FROM comprobantedetalle where comprobantedetalle.IdComprobante = 64700comprobante.idcomprobante)
FOR JSON PATH) as domiclio_entrega,

-- LINEAS
(SELECT 1 as id ,--comprobantedetalle.idpromocion as [lineas.id],
cdn.descripcion as detalle,
cdn.cantidad as cantidad,
cdn.valorneto as importe,
0 as descuento_n,
0 as descuento_p,
0 as iva_p
FROM comprobantedetalle cdn WHERE cdn.idcomprobante = comprobante.idcomprobante
FOR JSON PATH) as lineas

from comprobante
inner join Cliente on Cliente.idCliente = Comprobante.idcliente
INNER JOIN ClienteDatosContacto ON Cliente.idCliente = ClienteDatosContacto.idCliente
inner JOIN ClienteDomicilio ON Cliente.idCliente = ClienteDomicilio.idCliente 
inner join provincia cdprovincia on cdprovincia.idprovincia = clientedomicilio.idprovincia
inner join localidad cdlocalidad on cdlocalidad.idlocalidad = clientedomicilio.idlocalidad
inner join suscripcion on suscripcion.idsuscripcion = comprobante.idsuscripcion
inner join canalventa on canalventa.idcanalventa = suscripcion.idcanalventa
inner join mediocobro on mediocobro.idmediocobro = suscripcion.idmediocobro
where comprobante.idcomprobante between 64700 and 64702
--where comprobante.cae is null
for json path, root('ordenes')
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, evita usar mayúsculas sostenidas, que se asimila a que gritas (y veo que no es la idea). Lo otro: el idioma oficial de este sitio es el español, así que debo pedirte que edites y traduzcas tooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título, y de paso le quitas la mayúscula sostenida). Recuerda que la opción de editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Comment: jajaja, me volvi loco armando en ingles por que pense que era ingles el sitio! gracias por tus comentarios ahora lo modifico!